# Copy XREExeF and paste as file shortcut

Tags: javascript, file, firefox-addon, shortcut-file

In my addon I was launching Firefox profiles by doing this:

```
var exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []); //this gives path to executable
var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
process.init(exe);

var args = ['-P', profName, '-no-remote']; //-new-instance
if (url) {
    args.push('about:home');
    args.push(url);
}
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

So this adds command line arguments and launches it. However this leads to some problems. Users want to pin the icon and it just pins another `firefox.exe`. Users also try to change the icon.

Wikipedia says all OS support shortcuts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut

So I wanted to copy `XREExeF` and paste it as a shortcut and then add command line arguments to it.

Edit: 
Thanks to @nmaier I now know there is no cross-os method. Can you please show me os specific methods.

Comment: Apparently in Win7 if you launch a shortcut with the command line arguments of `-P "Profile Name Here" -no-remote` you can't right click on it to pin it. So this idea is dead. But still learning I dont know how to make shortcuts so interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Windows

In this example the shortcut created will be called "Mozilla Firef ya" and will open up a profile named "ya ya".

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []);

var myShortcut = FileUtils.getFile('Desk', ['Mozilla Firef ya.lnk']);
var myShortcutWin = myShortcut.QueryInterface(Ci.nsILocalFileWin);

var myScIcon = new FileUtils.File('C:\\Users\\Noitidart\\Downloads\\amo-puzzle.ico'); //myScIcon must be converted to ico if it isnt an ico
myShortcutWin.setShortcut(exe, null, '-P "ya ya"', 'Launches Mozilla Firefox with "ya ya" Profile', myScIcon);
```

- How to convert to ico:

  - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/77006d9201d0e1dfe2be#comment-1291328 (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24270884/1828637) this main gist also has a processIcon function taken from MXR

#### *nix (Desktop) (FF doesnt work on non-desktop *nix's anyways *i think*)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25516219/1828637

#### Mac

Use AppleScript here: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1126/shortcut-created-on-mac-with-osfile-but-cant-get-around-unidentified-developer-error/

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no cross-platform way to create shortcuts. In fact there is not even a cross-browser format for shortcuts, as [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut) you already referenced tells you. Instead each platform uses it's own type(s) of links:

- Windows: [`.lnk` files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx) and sometimes [hardlinks and junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- *nix: (Symbolic) links (`man 3 link`, `man symlink`, `man ln)
- Some *nix desktop environments: [`.desktop` files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).
- Other *nix desktop environments: Whatever they want, if any.

Each of these *things* behaves differently. NTFS/*nix hard links are not even files, but just different names for the same file.

Also, the *pinning* you're describing is specific to Windows, anyway. Other desktop environments may use completely different *pinning*, if they even offer a comparable feature at all, or at least their *pinning* equivalents may have completely different semantics.

Comment: Any way to make the shortcuts via FF XPCOM per os? Or does it have to go to js-ctypes?

Comment: I don't know of any XPCOM that will create such links for you.

Comment: For *nix I only need to support desktop environments right because firefox is only for *nix with desktops? Any ideas for making `.desktop` like file in mac?