# Interface of nsILocalFileMac

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-addon

I found this thing on MDN called [`nsILocalFileMac`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsILocalFileMac) I couldn't make too much sense of it. However there is this thing called "alias" and "followLinks". Is this synonymous with a "shortcut" or ".lnk" file on Windows?

If it is, how can I use this interface to make an "alias"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Unix systems you can make a shortcut like this, they are called symlink or alias files:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
var pathToTarget = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.macLocalApplicationsDir, 'Firefox.app');
var pathToAlias = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'ff.link'); //extension is .link, the file must not exist or unixErrno 17 ocurs
var promise_alias = OS.File.unixSymLink(pathToTarget, pathToAlias)
promise_alias.then(
  function(aVal) {
    console.log('Promise Fullfilled - promise_alias - ', aVal);
  },
  function(aReason) {
    console.error('Promise Rejected - promise_alias - ', aReason);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alias is very much like a "shortcut" / `.lnk` file used on Windows, they serve the same functions with different implementations.  An alias is more similar to a Unix symbolic link.

[You can read more about it on Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Mac_OS%29).

If you want to create an alias you can read about that [on Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Mac_OS%29#Managing_aliases), and [on Apple's support site here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA26514)

Comment: Thanks Erik! I was hoping to make the alias programmatically with XPCOM, kind of like how I made shortcut on windows here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25372783/1828637 do you know if possible?

Comment: Hi Erik, it says alias are supported by `Mac OS System 7` and later. Does that man `>= Mac OS X 10.7`?

Comment: Hi Erik maybe use nsiFile to createa file which contains a path to something? Maybe set `permissionsOfLink`? Im floundering here I can't figure out how to make an alias :(