# OS.File set chown and chmod (creating trusted launcher - ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create a shortcut that launches a profile on the desktop in Linux.

I'm using this code:

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []);
var args = '-P -dev -no-remote';

```
var name = "mysc";
var target = exe;
var cmd = "[Desktop Entry]\n";
cmd += "Name=" + name + "\n";
cmd += "Type=Application\n";
cmd += "Comment=Web Application\n";
cmd += "Exec=" + target.path + " " + args + "\n";
//cmd += "Icon=" + icon.path + "\n";

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")
var path = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'mysc.desktop');
Services.ww.activeWindow.alert(path)

let encoder = new TextEncoder();
let array = encoder.encode(cmd);
let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(path, array, {tmpPath: "file.txt.tmp"});
promise.then(
  function(aVal) {
    Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('success aVal = ' + uneval(aVal));
  },
  function(aRejReas) {
    Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('rejected for reason: ' + uneval(aRejReas))
  }
)
```

How can i set chown and chmod?

I found this code https://github.com/johnshih/releases-mozilla-aurora/blob/dc29053a4b1765cf94a8562130865036c373038e/toolkit/components/osfile/osfile_unix_back.jsm#L218

```
UnixFile.chmod =
    declareFFI("chmod", ctypes.default_abi,
        /*return*/
        Types.negativeone_or_nothing,
        /*path*/
        Types.path,
        /*mode*/
        Types.mode_t);
 UnixFile.chown =
    declareFFI("chown", ctypes.default_abi,
        /*return*/
        Types.negativeone_or_nothing,
        /*path*/
        Types.path,
        /*uid*/
        Types.uid_t,
        /*gid*/
        Types.gid_t);
```

Someone told me to set `chown noi` and `chmod +x` on the file because my path to desktop is: `/home/noi/Desktop/mysc.desktop` will fix this error here:
[image]

Maybe `OS.File.setPermissions`?

I tried this but it didnt work:

```
    var promise2 = OS.File.setPermissions(path, {
        unixMode: OS.Constants.libc.S_IRWXO
    });
    promise2.then(
        function(aVal) {
            console.log('promise2 success', 'aVal:', aVal);
        },
        function(aReason) {
            console.warn('promise2 rejected', 'aReason:', aReason);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how to set chown and chmod but I was able to create the file as trusted. It was along the lines of `OS.File.setPermission` but for some reason using `unixMod` and the flags of `OSConstants.libc.S_I*` like the docs recommended was not right.

This is how I made a trusted desktop shortcut:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")

var exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []);
var args = '-P dev -no-remote';

var name = "Mozilla Firefox - dev";
var target = exe;
var icon_path = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'beta.png');
var cmd = "[Desktop Entry]\n";
cmd += "Name=" + name + "\n";
cmd += "Type=Application\n";
cmd += "Comment=Web Application\n";
cmd += "Exec=" + target.path + " " + args + "\n";
cmd += "Icon=" + icon_path + "\n";


var path = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'mysc.desktop');

let encoder = new TextEncoder();
let array = encoder.encode(cmd);
let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(path, array, {tmpPath: "file.txt.tmp"});
promise.then(
  function(aVal) {
    console.log('aVal', aVal);
    var promise2 = OS.File.setPermissions(path, {unixMode: 0o4777});
    promise2.then(
     function(aVal) {
       console.log('promise2 success', 'aVal:', aVal);
     },
      function(aReason) {
        console.warn('promise2 rejected', 'aReason:', aReason);
      }
    );
  },
  function(aRejReas) {
    Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('rejected for reason: ' + uneval(aRejReas))
  }
);
```

Notice the `0o4777` instead of `OS.Constants.libc.S_IRWXO`, its weird, I didn't expect this at all and just got lucky searching github code base.