# Icon Container Files per OS

Tags: firefox-addon

I have 8 images:

- 16x16
- 24x24
- 32x32
- 48x48
- 64x64
- 96x96
- 128x128
- 256x256

I would like to save drawings from canvas and then make a single file for Windoes, Mac, Linux that contains all these icons so that based on users settings the file will select the proper sized icon.

- Windows uses container file `ico`

  - XP only uses 16, 24, 32, and 48
  - Win os'es greater than XP uses all i think
- Mac uses `icns`
- Linux uses `xpm`?

Posting here if anyone can help with it. Otherwise Ill be getting to this sometime in future so will add to solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Windows

Thanks to @nmaier work from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24270884/1828637

I wrote this function which takes an array of paths to images, it then converts to ico and saves it to a location. This is a copy paste example at this gist: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / MakeIcoOfPaths.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e3d9f61bd268368df37a)

ABSOLUTELY not possible without nmaier's awesome work in the topic linked.

## Linux

*Soon to come - will output `.xpm` file*

## Mac

*Soon to come - will output `.icns` file*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set different images based on the Operating system, or OS version etc

You can separate them in [Chrome registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#os)

From: [Missing buttons](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=2854787)

```
skin browser classic/1.0 browser/skin/classic/aero/browser/ os=WINNT osversion>=6
skin browser classic/1.0 browser/skin/classic/browser/ os!=WINNT
skin browser classic/1.0 browser/skin/classic/browser/ os=WINNT osversion<6
```

Comment: Thanks man I actually calrified, i have a canvas and made drawings on them. Put an image, then a badge. And now i want to save all the different sizes into a single file that can be used as an icon container file for the os'es firefox runs on.